# On a question about finite metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that every continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ has a finite Image. prove that, $X$ is finite.

I tried this:

Let $x_0$ be arbitrary element of $X$ and define: $f(x)=d(x,x_0)$. because  $f$  is continuous, by the hypothesis, $Im(f)=\{0,r_1,r_2,...,r_n\}\subset \mathbb R$.

If $X$ be infinite, for some $1\le j\le n$, the set $A=f^{-1}(r_j)$ should be infinite. I think, we should define another continuous function on $A$ which it's Image be infinite

Comment: I'm not sure it will be easy to prove that $A$ is finite, imagine $x_0$ is $(0,0)$ and the unit ball in contained in $X$.

Comment: Choose an $x_0 \in X$. Then define $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + d(x, x_0)}$. This is can be shown to be a continuous function. Try to go from her to show that if $X$ is infinite, then Im $f$ is infinite as well.

Comment: Let $X=\{(x,y)∣x^2+y^2=1\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$ and put: $x_0=(0,0)$ then $f(x)=1 or \frac{1}{2}$ for every $x\in X$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is useful.
You already showed that for any $x_0\in X$ there exists $r_1>0$ such that the $r_1$-ball around $x_0$ contains only $x_0$. In other words: $X$ is discrete.
But then *any* function $X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Hence if $X$ is infinite, it contains a subset that can be bijected with $\mathbb N$; any extension of this map to all of $X$ has infinite image - contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Suppose that $X$ is infinite. There are two cases.

- Show that if $X$ is discrete, then there is a continuous function from $X$ onto $\Bbb N$.
- If $X$ is not discrete, then there is a $p\in X$ that is a limit point of $X\setminus\{p\}$. Consider the function $$f_X\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto d(p,x)\;.$$